# How can I list all beans annotated with @Configuration in an application context?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How can I get a list of all active @Configuration beans from an application context so I can list them at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the application context and ask it by all beans annotated with `@Configuration` annotation, make sure you call once only the `ApplicationContext` instance, and not call it several times, then you can ask by beans with that annotation by following this:

```
Map<String, Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Configuration.class);
```